# Шляпы тормозят и/или не работают

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, новогодние-шляпы

Получил первую шляпу и:

- выпадающий список со шляпами грузился с полминуты
- шляпа на странице шляп грузилась с полминуты
- при попытке её надеть дважды получил сообщение об ошибке и третий раз об ограничении на выполнение действия раз в 10 секунд
- после обновления страницы на аватраке шляпы нет, а диалог не работает

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Хм.. Кажется, заработали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свободный перевод [ответа](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304373/) @balpha на аналогичный вопрос на MSE

---

На данный момент при обращении к доменам winterbash2017.stackexchange.com и cdn-prom.sstatic.net запросы идут в одно место, чего быть не должно (последний домен, который хранит статические файлы, должен был работать через CDN, о чем говорит его имя).

Как я понимаю, все эти запросы каким–то образом не понравились нашему верному серверу шляп. Несколько часов назад, я отключил функцию шляп для анонимных пользователей Stack Overflow, чтобы снизить трафик. Как результат, как я понимаю, все встало на свои места. Я включу шляпы для всех снова, как только мы правильно настроим сервера.

**Обновление**: теперь все должно работать, как и задумано.