# Шапки в шапке скачут

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, новогодние-шляпы

[image]

Снежинка появляется только после загрузки остальной страницы. Это выглядит быстрым, однако я за сегодня уже наверно с десяток раз успевал навести курсор на другую кнопку (например, уведомления), решить туда кликнуть, а на внезапно появляющуюся снежинку отреагировать уже не успевал и в результате из-за смещения кнопок кликал не туда и очень расстраивался. На метамете случайно ещё не предлагали забить место под снежинку заранее в html-коде, чтоб не скакало?

Comment: Та же проблема...

Comment: На сколько я знаю, все шляпы — это отдельный подгружаемый модуль, который, вероятно, подгружается после загрузке всей страницы. Модулем шляпы сделаны, чтобы один и тот же код можно было использовать на всех платформах без изменения. Возможно, проблема в вашем соединение, возможно, в нагрузке серверов. Если станет что–то известно, обязательно отпишусь.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, но место на кнопку всё равно можно зарезервировать.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну я не вижу каких-либо принципиальных причин невозможности прописывания html-кода сторонними подключаемыми модулями, разве что если движок сайта до ужаса кривой)

Comment: @Qwertiy Если я верно понимаю идею, то нет. Страничка сама по себе ничего не знает о шапках. Страничка создается из шаблона на сервере (или еще как–то). Снежинка добавляется у вас не клиенте, после загрузки самой станицы и кодов для шляп. При такой архитектуре, ничего не зарезервируешь.

Comment: @andreymal Хоть я и не разработчик, но никаких особых грубых ошибок не вижу, а дефекты есть везде. То, что вы видите — не есть дефект. Скорее, это следствие выбранного подхода. Повторюсь, я не знаю как именно реализован код шляп, это моя догадка. Как только что–то узнаю от авторов модуля, сразу отпишусь!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky но шаблон откуда-то знает, что нужно загрузить скрипт модуля! Точно так же ничего не мешает знать, что для модуля нужно немного html-кода. Такие вещи делаются очень легко, каждый первый модульный сайт так умеет, а если движок SO такое не позволяет, значит он кривой)

Comment: Ответ обновлён. // сс @NicolasChabanovsky

Comment: @andreymal Если движок такого не позволяет, это лишь значит, что он такого не позволяет. Обычно, ядро не знает о надстройках (и не должно знать).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky знать не должно, а предоставлять интерфейс для их подключения должно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вот и новый сезон шляп и шапка больше не прыгает: место зарезервировано заранее:

[image: скриншот до загрузки шляп]

а кнопка и шляпа появляются с задержкой

[image: скриншот после загрузки шляп]

Comment: Тоже заметил это изменение. Почему-то не могут совсем бесшовно это реализовать.

Comment: @älёxölüt, какое? Ничего же не скачет больше.

Comment: задержка с появлением же.

Comment: @älёxölüt, ну так нагрузка на сервер со шляпами большая - вот он и работает медленнее.

Comment: Большая нагрузка, чтобы загрузить снежинку? Смешно.

Comment: @älёxölüt, со всех сайтов сети же. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6548/178988

Comment: "теперь все должно работать, как и задумано". Хреново задумано, значит.

Comment: @älёxölüt, нормально задумано. Пока шапки ещё грузятся, ты уже можешь читать вопрос с ответами)

Comment: Я не о том, чтобы ждать загрузки всех шапок и т.п., чтобы прочитать вопросответы. Я о том, что картинку звёздочки (а не то, что она тянет за собой) можно бы отобразить одновременно со всеми другими значками в заголовке дабы избежать этого мерцания.

Comment: А смысл, если шапка всё равно появляется позже? К тому же, звёздочка, которая, вообще-то, снежинка, имеет два цвета - если есть новые шляпы и если нет.

Comment: Шапка появляется позже чем что? Разные цвета при наличии шляп это, конечно, меняет дело. Но, имхо, снежинка, появляющаяся одновременно с другими иконками, и меняющая цвет чуть позже (после обращения ко всем сервакам) было бы лучше, чем пустое место, превращающееся в снежинку нужного цвета. Жалко, что при ненависти к шляпам эту снежинку нельзя отключить вовсе.

Comment: _Жалко, что ... снежинку нельзя отключить_ - любопытно, а раньше она отключалась? Полагаю, что в том году отключалась. "Раньше было лучше!@TM" Сами допросились...:)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, если бы она отключалась совсем, то как бы удалось вернуть её обратно?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать подобный css:

```css
.secondary-nav .-item:nth-child(4):last-child {
  margin-left: 38px;
}
```

Только обязательно нужно, чтобы расширение, применяющие стили, применяло их до загрузки страницы, а не после.
Например, годится расширение [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=ru), но не годится расширение <s>[User CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-css/okpjlejfhacmgjkmknjhadmkdbcldfcb?hl=ru)</s>.

Comment: Кажется, в 2018-м починили?

Comment: @andreymal, да, поправили. Сразу не ответил, т. к. предполагал, что у меня может быть стиль из этого ответа, но сейчас убедился.