# Не надеваются шляпы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, новогодние-шляпы

Несмотря на то, что эта тема уже была недавно создана, все-таки хотелось бы о ней поговорить.

Во-первых, на сайте, хоть у меня и есть 3 шляпы в профиле, при нажатии на иконку Winter Bash выпадает надпись "Вы еще не заработали ни одной шляпы".
Во-вторых, при попытке надеть шляпу я получаю сообщение "Во время изменения шляпы возникла ошибка. Пожалуйста, попробуйте снова.".

Вот скриншоты:


[image: Шляпы в профиле]


[image: Шляпы при клике на Winter Bash]


[image: Доступные мне шляпы]


[image: Ошибка =(]


P. S. Не терпится надеть шляпу!




Сейчас новая заковырка: при попытке входа на сайт Winter Bash вылетает ошибка(((
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня работает...

Comment: А у меня нет =(

Comment: Уже раз десять побовал(

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6545/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот поэтому я и вынес вопрос в отдельную тему, что у всех все работает.

Comment: А у меня вот нет(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свободный перевод ответа @balpha.

---

Проблема была в некорректной обработке сервером шляп объединения учетных записей. Дефект устранен, все должно работать!

Comment: Это перевод какого ответа? Если он дан раньше [комментария](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6565/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%88%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bf%d1%8b/6571#comment25550_6566), то скорее всего проблема в другом.

Comment: @alexolut Перевод ответа из нашего внутреннего чата! :)

Comment: Ох уж эта ромбовидная кухонька ...

Comment: Т.е. получается ТС как-то притерпел объединение? Наверное без @Grundy не обошлось...

Comment: @alexolut Это история умалчивает.

Comment: Правда работает, спасибо!"""

Comment: Правда, за это время я успел накопить ещё 3 шляпы ;)

Answer (score 1):

У меня было точно так же. Спустя 12 часов всё заработало. Само :)

Comment: Не работает((((